# Stored procedure update query in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have data in table which is of type text so i am converting it to json. Based on id of data i want to update a value of column.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN is_json(data)
      THEN data::json #> '{id}'
    ELSE
      NULL
  END
FROM table;
```

```
UPDATE table SET hash = md5(
result from above query??
);
```

Some kind of:

How can i write the update query?

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN is_json(data)
      THEN data::json #> md5('{id}')
    ELSE
      NULL
  END
FROM table;
```

I hava json stored in a text column.
**data:**

```
{'id': 'e807b554-fd15-4f7c-bbc5-d9531c8174a9','array': ['a'], 'rank': 151}
```

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_json(input_text varchar) RETURNS boolean AS $$
  DECLARE
    maybe_json json;
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      maybe_json := input_text;
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
    END;

    RETURN TRUE;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

When i select the query:

```
select * from table where is_json(data);
```

I get empty row. Whereas data has json in form of text.

Comment: Try `maybe_json := input_text::json;`

Comment: did not work , still getting empty row.

Comment: when i do select (to_json(content::text) #>> '{}') from table;
I get:
{'id': 'e807b554-fd15-4f7c-bbc5-d9531c8174a9','array': ['a'], 'rank': 151}

Comment: but when i do  select to_json(data::text) #>> '{id}' from table;

It does not print anything @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
update mytable 
set hash = md5(case when is_json(data) then data::json #>> '{id}' end)
```

Or if you want to only update rows that contain valid json:

```
update mytable 
set hash = md5(data::json #>> '{id}')
where is_json(data)
```

Comment: It gives me:
ERROR:  function md5(json) does not exist
LINE 2: set hash = md5(data::json #> '{id}')
                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @EatPayBong: use `#>>` instead of `#>` to return the value as text, not json

Comment: I have one more issue the is_json gives me empty row, i have updated the question. Can you please look.